# Constructing a class in a template class

Tags: c++

I am studying about templates and typename keyword I am getting error in the following code:

```
 /*1)*/ #include<iostream>
 /*2)*/ #include<cstdio>
 /*3)*/ #include<stdlib.h>
 /*4)*/
 /*5)*/ using namespace std;
 /*6)*/
 /*7)*/ class out
 /*8)*/ {
 /*9)*/ public:
/*10)*/    int i;
/*11)*/    out(int i,int j):i{i},ob{j}{}
/*12)*/    class in
/*13)*/    {
/*14)*/    public:
/*15)*/        int j;
/*16)*/        in(int j):j{j}{}
/*17)*/    }ob;
/*18)*/ };
/*19)*/
/*20)*/ template<typename type>
/*21)*/ class temp
/*22)*/ {
/*23)*/ public:
/*24)*/   typename type::in ob(3);
/*25)*/   type ob1(4,4);
/*26)*/ };
/*27)*/
/*28)*/ int main()
/*29)*/ {
/*30)*/    out ob(1,1);
/*31)*/    out::in ob1(2);
/*32)*/    temp<out> t;
/*33)*/    cout<<ob.i<<" "<<ob.ob.j<<endl;
/*34)*/    cout<<ob1.j<<endl;
/*35)*/    cout<<t.ob.j<<endl;
/*36)*/    cout<<t.ob1.i<<" "<<t.ob1.ob.j;
/*37)*/ }
```

The code shows the following error

```
      Line                        Error

      |24|  error: expected identifier before numeric constant
      |24|  error: expected ',' or '...' before numeric constant
      |25|  error: expected identifier before numeric constant
      |25|  error: expected ',' or '...' before numeric constant
            In function 'int main()':
      |35|  error: 't.temp<type>::ob<out>' does not have class type
      |36|  error: 't.temp<type>::ob1<out>' does not have class type
      |36|  error: 't.temp<type>::ob1<out>' does not have class type
      === Build failed: 7 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 4 second(s)) ===
```

If i change the two lines

typename type::in ob(3);

type ob1(4,4);

To

typename type::in ob=typename type::in(3);

type ob1=type(4,4);

It will works fine and producing following output:

```
          1 1
          2
          3
          4 4
          Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 0.847 s
          Press any key to continue.
```

But i want to know why the error shows, How can i solve the error in above code Please help me?

Thanks for helping.

Comment: If possible, consider replacing leading `XX)` with trailing `// XX` (or leading `/* XX */`), so anyone can try to compile your code as is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to initialize variables in the definition of a class you have to use assignement syntax or curly braces. Plain paranthesis is not allowed.

```
typename type::in ob=typename type::in(3);
type ob1=type(4,4);

typename type::in ob{3};
type ob1{4,4};
```

This is unrelated to templates and works the same for all classes. One of the reasons is to make parsing easier for the compiler. As mentioned in the comments most vexing parse is an example when disambiguating between an initialization and a function declaration can be done by using `{}` instead of `()`.

Comment: Thanks for Helping , It works Well But why to use curly braces

Comment: Google the Most Vexing Parse.

Comment: @Srilakshmikanthanp In the end the short answer is because the language says so. The reason it says so is to make parsing easier. `{}` is always an initialization while `()` could be a number of different things.